# C# Canvas resize

Tags: c#, xaml, wpf-controls

I want to change those canvas ellipse height and width, if i click a button it will increase 1 both.
But i didn't find canvas resize function, how can i resize the ellipse.

and i also want to add a canvas contain picture,how can i do it.

```
Canvas Name="MainCanvas"
        <Ellipse Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Height="15" Name="headEllipse" Stroke="Black" Width="15" Fill="Orange" />
        <Ellipse Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="0" Height="15" Name="rightEllipse" Stroke="Black" Width="15" Fill="SlateGray" />
        <Ellipse Canvas.Left="93" Canvas.Top="0" Fill="SpringGreen" Height="15" Name="leftEllipse" Stroke="Black" Width="15" />
        <Ellipse Canvas.Left="150" Canvas.Top="0" Height="15" Name="KneeRightEllipse" Stroke="Black" Width="15" Fill="Salmon" />
        <Ellipse Canvas.Left="200" Canvas.Top="0" Fill="White" Height="15" Name="KneeLeftEllipse" Stroke="Black" Width="15" />
        <Ellipse Canvas.Left="235" Canvas.Top="0" Fill="PaleGreen" Height="15" Name="ShoulderEllipse" Stroke="Black" Width="15" />
    </Canvas>
```

Comment: is this wpf, winrt or silverlight?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be Silverlight. Try to define handler for `Click` event of a `Button` and use this method (it should work both in WPF and Silverlight, but I have tested it only in WPF):

```
private void btnEnlargeEllipses_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (UIElement control in MainCanvas.Children)
        {
            Ellipse ellipse = (control as Ellipse);
            if (ellipse != null)
            {
                ellipse.Width += 1;
                ellipse.Height += 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Alternatively, you could define a `DependencyProperty`, bind ellipses widths end heights to it and increment it inside button's `Click` event handler.